# Does Google Cloud API Gateway come with a Configurable Timeout?

Tags: google-cloud-api-gateway

I've looked through the [Google Cloud API Gateway docs](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs) and searched [the public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=api%20gateway%20timeout) but haven't been able to find a mention of it one way or another.

The closest I've come is [this google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/api-gateway-users/c/mODH20NOVTQ/m/Rc4j5JpgBQAJ) from 4 months ago, which suggests that it may be 60 seconds, but I haven't been able to confirm this or determine if it's out-of-date yet.

TL;DR

I'm looking for alternatives to AWS API Gateway (which has a fixed 30 second timeout) and so am trying to figure out if GCP API Gateway would work as an alternative on this particular point.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, GCP API gateway does support custom timeout lengths. In your open api spec, underneath "x-google-backend:", insert "deadline: z" where z is the number of seconds till timeout.

Example:

```
    x-google-backend:
         address: [this-is-your-address]
         deadline: 60.0
```

The above will give a deadline of 60 seconds.

Comment: @grunet Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question?

Comment: I'm unsure, not having anything handy to try it on. A GCP doc reference would be nice

Comment: @grunet Please have a look at these GCP docs: 
[1](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-backend)
[2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#deadline)

Comment: Yeah like I mentioned in the other answer's comment I think these docs are for the old Cloud Endpoints products, not the newer ones that include API gateway (though I might've just been misunderstanding that this whole time...)

Comment: I tried the solution and can confirm that the deadline attribute works as expected

Comment: GCP doc on deadline: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-backend